# How to call maven-resources-plugin then exec-maven-plugin then again maven-resources-plugin

Tags: java, spring, maven

I want to copy a excel using maven-resources-plugin and creating some property files from that excel using exec-maven-plugin. And the newly created properties needs to be attached with the build. I could able to create the property files but these property files are not included in the build(jar).
Can anyone please help me to solve this.
Or is there any way to do these.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create multiple executions of the `maven-resources-plugin` and assign them to [a different `phase`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).

For example, you could do:

- `generate-resources` phase: first thing you need to do
- `process-resources` phase: `exec-maven-plugin` to process the resource
- `prepare-package` phase: whatever run of `maven-resources-plugin` (again) you want

You would pick phases that make sense for what the plugin is doing, you can take some liberty to make things work.

You can configure the executions like so:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>first</id>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>jar</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        ...
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>second</id>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      ...
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

Comment: Thank you Sander, but for my case this solution was not worked, but I solved the case by, first copied the excel using resource plugin and then created the property files while starting the application using a class with postconstruct method.